# Display number of collection items in a View with Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, single-page-application, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

How do I display the number of items in a collection? I tried to use `collection.models.length` or `collection.length` nothing works. I even even created a method in the `Backbone.Collection` called `count()` to return the length of the collection but nothing happens.

Template:

```
<p>you have <span class="caller-num">0</span> missed calls.</p>
```

Collection:

```
// callers collection
define([
'jquery',
'underscore', 
'backbone',
'models/caller'
], function($, _, Backbone, Caller) {

  var CallersList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Caller,
    url: 'js/json/callers.json',

    // had to do this because it's the 'callers' key that has the array of objects, the json
    parse: function(data) {
      return data.callers;
    },

    count: function() {
      return this.length;
    }
  });

  return CallersList;

});
```

Missed Calls View : showing the number of missed calls

```
define([
'jquery', 
'underscore', 
'backbone',
'collections/callers-list',
'text!templates/missed-calls-number-template.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, CallersList, missedCallsNumTemplate) {

  var MissedCallsNumberView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.number-of-callers',
    template: _.template(missedCallsNumTemplate),

    initialize: function() {

      var callers = new CallersList;
      this.$el.find('.caller-num').text(callers.count());
      //this.$el.find('.caller-num').text($('.caller').length); /* this doesn't work either */
    },

    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.template(this.model));

      return this;
    }
  });

  return MissedCallsNumberView;

});
```

AppView:

```
define([
'jquery', 
'underscore', 
'backbone',
'collections/callers-list',
'views/callers-view',
'views/missed-called-num-view'
], function($, _, Backbone, CallersList, CallersView, MissedCallsNumberView) {

  var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.app',

    initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this, 'render');
      this.render();

      var callers = new CallersList;
      callers.fetch({ reset: true });
      this.$el.find('.caller-num').text(callers.models.length);
    },

    render: function() {
      var callersView = new CallersView({ collection: CallersList }),
          mcn = new MissedCallsNumberView({ collection: CallersList });

      this.$el.append(callersView.render().el);
      this.$el.find('header').append(mcn.render().el);
    }
  });

  return AppView;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`length` should work on your collection in the render method of the `MissedCallsNumberView`

```
render: function() {
  this.$el.html(this.template(this.model));
  this.$el.find('.caller-num').text(callers.length);
  return this;
}
```

I think the problem is that you are creating a new collection in the initialization of your view. You probably want the collection you passed when creating the view:

```
var callers = this.collection;
```

Comment: Thanks @Hazaart. Where do I put the code, in the AppView, Missed Call View, etc? Because I tried `this.$el.find('.caller-num').text(callers.length);` before and it didn't work. Even doing a `console.log`, always shows `0`, what's going on?

Comment: @Shaoz I have updated my answer, please try this way.

Comment: I've tried your fix but it's still doesn't work. Which View are you talking about, as I've kinda created collections in all the views?

Comment: The MissedCallsNumberView. This is where you want to display the count right? If you debug, do you see any values in your collection when initializing the view?

Comment: Hi @Hazaart, it's still doesn't work and it's still always showing `0` in the `console.log` after debugging. But I have done a jsfiddle, so maybe you can shed some light on this: http://jsfiddle.net/xps6t/

Comment: @Shaoz I have updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xps6t/4/ . You are making a new collection but you are not filling it anywhere. I am now passing your fake JSON as such: `var thecallers = new CallersList(json);` This is probably not the functionality you'll be needing but as you can see `thecallers.length` now logs `3` thus `.length` does work.

Comment: Thanks again, @Hazaart But when doing manual data, the collection is fine. But when fetching json from a server that's where the issue is. The `console.log` and the View still shows `0`, even though I called `callers.fetch({reset: true})`. Why is that?